# Prove intersection of trapezium lies on perpendicular bisector of PQ

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

[image: Image here]

Let ABCD be a trapezium with AB and CD being parallel. 
Let P and Q be points lying on AD and BC respectively, such that $\angle$APB=$\angle$CPD and $\angle$AQB=$\angle$CQD.
Let E be the point of intersection of diagonals AC and BD.

Prove that point E lies on the perpendicular bisector of PQ.

My idea for solving this was to prove that the triangle $\triangle$PEQ is isosceles, which would give us the thesis instantly.
I've also managed to prove that angles $\angle$APB=$\angle$CPD=$\angle$AQB=$\angle$CQD, which also means that points A, B, P, Q lie on one circle, and points C, D, P, Q lie on another. 
I've tried to apply Stewart's Theorem but it didn't get me far. 
For example, if you draw a line parallel to PC going through point B we obtain an isosceles triangle with cevian AB with third vertex being K. By Stewart's Theorem and simmilar triangles $\triangle$CPD and $\triangle$BKA we have

$AB^2$=$BP^2$-AP$\times$DP$\frac{AB}{CD}$.

Like so we obtain:

$AB^2$=$AQ^2$-BQ$\times$CQ$\frac{AB}{CD}$

$CD^2$=$CP^2$-AP$\times$DP$\frac{CD}{AB}$

$CD^2$=$DQ^2$-BQ$\times$CQ$\frac{CD}{AB}$.

I've also tried applying analytical geometry but that got me nowhere.

After that I've encountered a wall. Would really appreciate help.

Comment: Also the thesis would be proven if it was shown that point E lies on line connecting centers of mentioned circles ABPQ and CDPQ.

Comment: There is something wrong with either the problem statement or your diagram. Point P was drawn on AD instead as stated (on AB). Also, if P is on AB, $\angle APB = ... = 180^0$.

Comment: Indeed I made a mistake when formulating the problem, i meant AD and BC.